# Entity Framework Provider Type could not be loaded when running unit test, debugs fine

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, unit-testing

I have a .NET 4.5.2 unit test project in VS2013 version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4.  EntityFramework 6.1.3 is installed in the project via NuGet.  The same version of EntityFramework is in all projects in the solution that use EntityFramework.

When I **run** a particular MS-Test unit test, I get a System.InvalidOperationException with the message "The Entity Framework provider type 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer' registered in the application config file for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient' could not be loaded.  Make sure that the assembly-qualified name is used and that the assembly is available to the running application.  See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information".

However, when I **debug** that test, the test runs through all the way and passes.  What gives?

Comment: And yes, I've uninstalled and re-installed Entity, and cleaned and rebuilt the solution.

Comment: I had the same problem: first, make sure it points to the right assembly. then you have to ensure in code that the assembly gets actually loaded before accessing the provider, for example by binding the type to a local variable.

Comment: Ok, binding the type of my DbContext to a variable does in fact solve the problem, but I wish there were another way.

Comment: Actually, the binding doesn't work consistently.  If I run the test repeatedly, it sometimes passes and sometimes fails, with no obvious pattern to it.  This is not a sufficient solution.

Comment: not of DbContext. of your providerfactory (with EF).